# Not able to create a geoprocessing package in ArcMap using my own Network Dataset and associated data

Tags: arcmap, geoprocessing, routing

I went through the following two examples to get an idea of how to create a custom, local Routing Task . . .

This is a walkthrough that takes you step by step through the creation of your first routing geoprocessing package:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/...00000m5000000/
And here is the second part, that completes the picture and shows you how to run it from code:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/...00000m6000000/

I am able to create the gpk using the above mentioned link instructions. However, when I attempted to create a gpk using my own data, I got an error message each time (General function failure ERROR 999999: Error executing function). When I researched this error, I didn't find anything helpful. 
I am using a map document that contains a Network Dataset created from a Shapefile Feature class.
The settings that I use to create the package are . . .
Support ArcGIS Runtime enabled (other two options are disabled)
Summary and Tags detail filled in
Is there any way to find out more info on the error? I don't know why it's failing, but I keep changing little details and trying it again.

Thanks,
Renee

Comment: the 2nd link you posted doesn't work. I assume you run your code from out the ArcGIS GUI? Try to hardcode your sources (path, filename) and run it from the console. What error message do you get now?

Comment: The 2nd link, using the example data, didn't work for me either.  However, I thought that the whole approach made sense, and perhaps I could use my own data (which I will be using ultimately) and get the desired results.  Anyway, I will try your suggestion and see how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: I was not able to figure out how to follow your suggestion.  I was able to save the model as a Python script and run it from the command window, but I need to be able to take the result of running the model inside ArcMap and share that as a geoprocessing package from the command line (could not figure out how to do that).

Comment: It is very difficult to help you like this because I find it hard to even narrow down what goes wrong and where. The general function failure is just a way of ArcGIS telling you: Ups, something went wrong but I don't know what. This can be a simple misspelling or wrong path.

Comment: Yes, I know that it's hard to offer a suggestion when you're not actually here at my computer working on it.  I've been hacking away hoping that something will jump out at me.  Sometimes that all you can do.  Thanks for your suggestion.  I'll keep trying and keep researching for a solution online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hacking away for a while, and trying to emulate the steps in the above mentioned step-by-step tutorial, I was able to determine that the reason I wasn't able to create a geoprocessing package was because the Network Dataset that I was using was created in a regular folder rather than a File Geodatabase Feature Dataset.

Comment: Evidently, I could programmatically create a Network Dataset and have it reside in a regular file folder.  However, creating it using Arc Catalog requires that it be in a File Geodatabase Feature Dataset.

Comment: I'd like to know more. Was this only with Runtime enabled and using a shapefile-network dataset? This is an "older" type of network dataset. There is no direct conversion between them and fgdb-network dataset, as such I could imagine packaging failing if it tried to convert the shapefile-network dataset at package time. Obviously it shouldnt fail with a 9999 error, thus I'd like to understand the problem more  
(I work at Esri as an engineer with GP packaging)

Comment: Yes, this gpk was created with Runtime enabled and using a shapefile ND.  Right now I'm having another problem with getting this gpk to work with my code, that uses my own raster data.  I created the gpk using the following example . . . http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/concepts/index.html#/How_to_author_and_publish_a_geoprocessing_model/0170000000m5000000/.  Then when I created the C# code using the following example . . . http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/concepts/index.html#/How_to_develop_a_point_to_point_routing_application/0170000000m6000000/

Comment: I was able to get it to run using my map package that I created (with my own data).  However, when it runs and I click the "Solve" button, I can only get the Route to display that was displayed when I created the gpk from the result.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're encountering - *NIM086174 Unable to create geoprocessing package with a shapefile based network dataset. A network dataset stored in a geodatabase packages successfully.*
We're currently investigating a fix for the next service pack with this (10.1 sp2), but at the time of this posting I can't guarantee a fix will make the next service pack.