# Is it possible to create a map package of a network dataset (ESRI ArcGIS 10.1)?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, map-package, network-dataset

Is it possible to create a map package of a network dataset (ESRI ArcGIS 10.1)? I tried publishing it as a map package, but I can't seem to insert the network itself (the "New Route" part, not the extracted layers of the stops and the route and barriers).

I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34792/not-able-to-create-a-geoprocessing-package-in-arcmap-using-my-own-network-dataset), but the links are broken, and I can't seem to get info.

EDIT: I found [this](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/38003-Routing-with-Local-Data?highlight=network#2) from ESRI forums, stating that "at this time(2011) the Runtime does not support the RouteTask with local resources. Routing is supported by geoprocessing model and then creating a Geoprocessing Package (gpk) with runtime support enabled from that model."  - As I understand it, I need to build a model. But I still don't understand if I can work with my data or not ( I need the tool, based on specific layers, not a general tool, and not with only route results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this question: it is possible to create a package out of the ability to map a route(built into a model), but it's not a map package (MPK) but a geoprocessing package (GPK) , for more details see [this link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/concepts/index.html#/How_to_author_and_publish_a_geoprocessing_model/0170000000m5000000/) (ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF > How to author and publish a geoprocessing model)

Answer (score 3):

According the [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000q5000000) of ESRI it should be possible.
"Some datasets reference other datasets. For example, you may have a topology dataset that references four feature classes. Other examples of datasets that reference other datasets include Geometric Networks, **Networks**, and Locators. When consolidating or packaging a layer based on these types of datasets, the participating datasets will also be consolidated or packaged."

Comment: I saw that, but I'm not certain they don't mean only the route layer itself and not the ability to calculate networks.